# Enabling Back Projection through a Custom Layer

Tags: tensorflow

When running the notebook available at:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1rMYs5bQzr1ubCnsWTgJNecYwEQamXwsn

I get the following error:

```
    ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['sequential/conv2d/kernel:0', 'sequential_1/conv2d_1/kernel:0', 'sequential_1/batch_normalization/gamma:0', 'sequential_1/batch_normalization/beta:0', 'sequential_2/conv2d_2/kernel:0', 'sequential_2/batch_normalization_1/gamma:0', 'sequential_2/batch_normalization_1/beta:0', 'sequential_3/conv2d_3/kernel:0', 'sequential_3/batch_normalization_2/gamma:0', 'sequential_3/batch_normalization_2/beta:0', 'sequential_4/conv2d_4/kernel:0', 'sequential_4/batch_normalization_3/gamma:0', 'sequential_4/batch_normalization_3/beta:0', 'sequential_5/conv2d_5/kernel:0', 'sequential_5/batch_normalization_4/gamma:0', 'sequential_5/batch_normalization_4/beta:0', 'sequential_6/conv2d_6/kernel:0', 'sequential_6/batch_normalization_5/gamma:0', 'sequential_6/batch_normalization_5/beta:0', 'Variable:0', 'Variable:0'].
```

I suspect that it is because my last layer is highly customised which is causing TensorFlow to struggle when back projecting through. I am quite new to this though, so I could be getting that wrong.

I have created a final layer which converts a circle centre, a rectangle centre, and a rectangle rotation into an image mask for use within a GAN. The aim is to replace the "decoder" arm of the UNet used within the Pix2Pix example (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/pix2pix).

I have my custom layer all hooked up, but unfortunately it appears the optimiser doesn't like it. I suspect it's because it has no idea how to back project through my layer. Is there a way to define a custom back projection within TensorFlow? If that is possible then I can just inform the neural net how to go backwards through it and hopefully it would then work.

Any tips/feedback/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Simon

Answer (score 0):

So, I worked it out. I needed to move my custom layer out of the model, let the model conclude with the 5 parameters (field centre x, field centre y, field rotation, bb_centre x and bb_centre y). Then when I wanted to pass the image through to the discriminator within the `train_step` function, there I would decode into the mask:

```py
@tf.function
def train_step(input_image, target_mask, target_encoding, epoch):
    with tf.GradientTape() as gen_tape, tf.GradientTape() as disc_tape:
        gen_output = generator(input_image, training=True)

        gen_output_image = decode_batch(gen_output)

        disc_real_output = discriminator([input_image, target_mask], training=True)
        disc_generated_output = discriminator([input_image, gen_output_image], training=True)

        gen_total_loss, gen_gan_loss, gen_l1_loss = generator_loss(disc_generated_output, gen_output, target_encoding)
        disc_loss = discriminator_loss(disc_real_output, disc_generated_output)

    generator_gradients = gen_tape.gradient(gen_total_loss,
                                          generator.trainable_variables)
    discriminator_gradients = disc_tape.gradient(disc_loss,
                                               discriminator.trainable_variables)

    generator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(generator_gradients,
                                          generator.trainable_variables))
    discriminator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(discriminator_gradients,
                                              discriminator.trainable_variables))

    with summary_writer.as_default():
        tf.summary.scalar('gen_total_loss', gen_total_loss, step=epoch)
        tf.summary.scalar('gen_gan_loss', gen_gan_loss, step=epoch)
        tf.summary.scalar('gen_l1_loss', gen_l1_loss, step=epoch)
        tf.summary.scalar('disc_loss', disc_loss, step=epoch)
```

A notebook that no longer raises an error (but still needs work) can be found at:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ozCjHHL5weA9daESMPgPhmbNx1rZWngc